# Natvis with multiple base classes

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, natvis

I'm working in a framework that does a lot of inheritance, and I've found that Natvis for one base class will interfere with that for another.

Here's a dumb example:

```
class MainBase {};
class ExtraBase {};
class Derived: MainBase, ExtraBase {};
```

With this natvis:

```
<Type Name="MainBase">
  <Expand>
    <Item Name="MainBaseItem">23</Item>
  </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="ExtraBase">
  <Expand>
    <Item Name="ExtraBaseItem">42</Item>
  </Expand>
</Type>
```

...I get this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dMNu.png

[image]

The expansion for MainBaseItem has shown up fine, but the one for ExtraBaseItem is nowhere to be seen.

In my real-world case, the natvis for the MainBase equivalent is very important, so I can't solve the problem by adding **Inheritable="false"** to it. It's also not practical to add specialised natvis for the derived class itself - there are thousands of derived classes. Given these unhelpful constraints, is there anything I can do to make ExtraBaseItem show up?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Type Name="ExtraBase">
  <Expand>
    <!-- Example of hierarchical class shown below-->
    <Item Name="MainBaseItem [base]">(MainBaseItem*)this</Item>
  </Expand>
</Type>
```

Idk if i understand this correct ....

Comment: My question wasn't very clear - in my example, the ExtraBaseItem 42 line represents some important property of ExtraBase which I want to make visible. I've edited the question to hopefully make it a bit clearer.